# About the Selenium getTitle() Method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In some instances, the getTitle() method does not work for me.

Take a look.

```
@Test
public void testTitleReliability() {

    driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    boolean title = driver.getTitle() == "Google";

    if(title)

        System.out.println("I am working correctly");

    else if(!title)

        System.out.println("I am broken!");
```

However, it will work with this:

```
@Test
public void testTitleReliability() {

    driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    boolean title = driver.getTitle().contains("Google");

    if(title)

        System.out.println("I am working correctly");

    else if(!title)

        System.out.println("I am broken!");
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

"==" just check if two reference variable are pointing two the same object in Java heap and since String is immutable in Java and maintained in String pool two String literal refer same String object which gives sense that "==" can be used to compare string which is incorrect. always use equals() method for equality check and compareTo method for actual string comparison.

Comment: That makes sense and thanks for the answer. I'm curious, when I execute this test, I don't get any errors. Do you know why?

Comment: Well the code is "correct" but your boolean will always be False. So probably you always get: I'm broken in your console. Now why put the else if? when you just can use else

Comment: When two objects are tried to compare using `==` their referencial check is done, which lands into false as the reference is not same, and hence here `.equals()` method should always be taken in consideration for checking the equality rather `==`. Always make up the habit. Good luck, happy coding!!!